# d3.json - can not load json file locally, only from URL

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want to load some json data for a d3 visualization. Calling the json file from a URL works fine, but when i download the same file to the local folder, it throws an error.

This works fine:

```
var q = require("d3-queue");

q.queue()
 .defer(d3.json, "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/world-atlas@2/countries-110m.json")
 .await(ready);
```

This does NOT work:

```
q.queue()
 .defer(d3.json, "countries-110m.json")
 .await(ready);
```

Throws the console error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`.

**Question:**
How can i load json data from the local folder?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: By local you mean a possibly relative path on a local server or do you mean from the file system?

Comment: By local i mean from my project folder. The error occurs when i download the json file from the link, put it in the project folder and try to read it from there.

Comment: I run a local server using parceljs, https://parceljs.org/

Comment: I still dont know why i can not load the json file locally, i uploaded it now to a gitub page and just load it from there which works fine.